# Amazon service for internet of things?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

Does amazon AWS have decent service for internet-of-things type applications (e.g. NEST thermostat, Wifi controlled appliances)? We would like to connect up to 2 million devices through the cloud. I can see how you might be able to do this with Amazon SQS and the Elastic Beanstalk, however I was hoping that there might be a better way that is less custom. For example, is there a good rules engine for SQS messaging?

I know that the NEST thermostat has solved a similar problem.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 2):

Try [Temboo](https://www.temboo.com/). Temboo offers a platform containing methods for 100+ APIs, databases, and code utilities, the Library and the Temboo platform are accessible via the Temboo SDK in seven programming languages, the Temboo REST API, and the Arduino Yún.